# "There are there only 3 papers" Vs. "There are there 3 papers only"

Tags: adverbs

From the two following choices, is there one choice correct only or both can be correct and it's a matter of style?  I'm not sure where I should to put the adverb "only" in such sentences.

> "There are there **only** 3 papers."

or

> "There are there 3 papers **only**."

Comment: Why two "there"s? Is it a typo or something?

Comment: No. The second is adverb (the opposite of "**here**"). https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there

Comment: Oh OK,  I see. that position of adverb was a little bit unfamiliar to my learner eyes.

Comment: You could say "There are *over* there only 3 papers." where "there are" refers to existence and "over there" refers to location. Though the normal phrasing would be "There are only 3 papers over there."

Answer (score 1):

Are you intending to say that there are "only" 3 papers in a specific *place*? If so, the correct way of saying this would be:

> "There are **only** 3 papers **there.**

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to say exactly. Then "there are there" never correct?

Comment: No, it would never be correct. And I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: Thank you. The same rule for "there is there". isn't it?

Comment: I guess it should be it's there not there's there (?)

Comment: @Cardinal I'm sorry. I didn't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean I'm guessing you mean "it's there" by "There is there "

Comment: No, it's (there is there) just a part of a full sentence. "There is there one man." for example.

Comment: @Archimedean_Point: **"There"** is an [adverb of place](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adverbs-of-Place.htm). The general rule is that an object of place is put immediately after an *intransitive* verb and after the *object* of a *transitive* verb.  So, it must be "There is a man there," because the adverb of place is put after the object *man*.